# Need help writing a reminder to myself in latin. - out of curiosity, knowledge. out of life, wisdom

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

This is what I want to remind myself everyday (probably tattoo it someday too):

> out of curiosity, knowledge.
> out of life, wisdom.

Is this how I’d write it?

> ex curiositate, scientia
> ex vita, sapientia

Comment: Thank you @cmw!